# My question is about the words "when" & "while" in the sentences

Tags: participle-phrases

My question is about the words "when" & "while" in the sentences (when/while doing; when a + noun (instead of "when I was" etc.)).

Could you please explain 2 and let me know if 1, 6, 7 are correct?

> 1. When I entered the room / when entering the room / entering the room, I found her playing the piano
> 2. a. When she was a child / when a child, she liked to read books
>      b. When he was a student / when a student, he often missed classes

As we can't use "being": being a child (my English language book says we can't).

However, "being" is used in the following sentences (found in the internet):

> 3. So I, being a great girlfriend, tried to help him out
> 4. I used to make a living, being the sheriff in this town here
> 5. Being a pastor, I started reading the Bible

So what's the difference between A and B sentences:

> A. When a child, she liked to read books
>   B. Being a pastor, I started reading the Bible

I'm going to ask in another way: in which cases we should use "being a student" and when is it better to say "when I was a student/when a student"?

> 6. While I was taking a shower / while taking a shower / taking a shower, I heard a strange noise in the kitchen
> 7. While he was in Berlin / while in Berlin, he made some new friends

Comment: You could substitute the word “being” in the sentences above with “because I am” and the context would be correct, but the same cannot be said when substituting “when” with “because I am”.

Answer (score 1):

All of the sentences are fine.

Although just *taking a shower, I heard . . .* is quite unusual and would not normally be used. Verbs that convey an ongoing action are most often preceded by something like *while*, *when*, *in the middle of*, *before*, *after*, or some other type of reference to time.

---

However, either your English book is wrong or you've misinterpreted it. There is nothing wrong with the phrase **being a child** per se. There's only a problem with it in certain contexts.

> ✔ When a child, she liked to read books.

This sentence is fine.

It's the same thing as saying that she liked to read books when she **was** a child.

> ✔ Being a child, she was unable to vote.

This sentence is *also* fine.

In this case, however, what it means is that she was unable to vote **because** she was a child.

> ✘ Being a child, she liked to read books.

While there is nothing wrong with the *syntax* of this sentence, it's wrong  because it's nonfactual (or, illogical with respect to reality).

It's not true that children like reading books **because** they are children. Many children *don't* like reading books.

---

The same rationale holds true for **being a pastor**.

> ✔ Being a pastor, I started reading the Bible.

You started reading the Bible **because** you were a pastor. That's completely rational.

> ✘ Being a pastor, I couldn't touch my toes.

There's nothing about being a pastor that prevents you from touching your toes.

Comment: @JasonBassford Do you think people say *When a child, she liked to read books* nowadays?

Comment: @userr2684291 - I’m with you; it rings a bit odd to me, too. _When **she was** a child, she liked to read books._ I think one could argue it’s grammatical either way, but it sure sounds a little unnatural to me.

Comment: @J.R. The OED (**2nd edition**) says: "Also *ellipt.* with only the predicate expressed, e.g. *when a boy* = 'when he (I, etc.) was a boy'; *when cold* = 'when it is cold.'" and has this citation from 1779: *He lost his father when an infant*. Webster's Dictionary (**1961**) says: "at or during the time that : while", with *on one occasion, when a boy, I went fishing with three other boys — W.J.Reilly* as one of the citations. [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/when), however, has "at or during the time that : while", and *went fishing when he was a boy*.

Comment: @userr2684291 - Yeah, I’m not surprised to find it in the OED. But it still sounds like a turn of phrase I’m more likely to read in an old book than hear during a meeting at work.

Comment: @userr2684291 Personally, *when a child* specifically is irrelevant; I would almost never use **any** *when [something | verb], [someone] [verb]* construction. I would opt instead for *when [someone] [helper verb+verb | verb], [someone] [verb]*. But it *sounds* natural to me in the context of newspaper headlines or other elliptical statements.